# Jetty 8 WebSocket and Session

Tags: jetty, websocket, httpsession

im building a little web app that uses jetty 8 as server and websockets.

On client (browser) side: the user opens with his browser my index.html and that opens and establishes a new WebSocket connection with my jetty server.

On server side, i have a WebSocketServlet that listens on incomming WebSocket connection.

```
    @Override
public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String arg1) {
    System.out.println("doWebSocketConnect");
    System.out.println("WebSocket "+request.getSession().getId());
    return new UserWebSocket(request.getSession());
}
```

UserWebSocket is a class that implements jetty's WebSocket.OnTextMessage interface for receiving and sending messages via websockets.

So far so good, everything works fine so far.

So what i now want to do, is to work with HttpSession to identify the current user, because
the index.html site can also do some ajax calls on other (non WebSocket) Servlets, like submit some simple form data via HTTP POST etc.

For example have a look at my SearchServlet:

```
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet{

...

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(request.getSession());
}
...
}
```

My problem is, that this two servlets (WebSocketServlet and SearchServlet) have two diffrent HttpSession object with two diffrent HttpSession ids:

for exmaple my WebSocketServlet have got the session id = 1dwp0u93ght5w1bcr12cl2l8gp on doWebSocketConnect() and the SearchServlet got the session id = 1sbglzngkivtf738w81a957pp, but the user is still in the same browser and on the same page (index.html) and have not reloaded the page etc. The time between establishing a WebSocket connection and the SearchServlet call is just a few seconds ...

Any suggestions?

EDIT: btw.
Both Servlets are in the same ServletContext:

```
ServletContextHandler servletContext = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContext.setContextPath("/servlets");
        servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder( new MyWebSocketServlet()),"/liveCommunication");
        servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder( new SearchServlet()),"/search");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible causes that I can see.

**1** - Your server is not correctly configured. Since you haven't provided the details about how you're running Jetty, and how you've configured it, it's certainly possible that you've introduced a problem there.

**2** - It's actually a timing issue.
I assume your index.html is static content, so it doesn't create a session on its own.

Within the index.html there is some javascript that will launch two separate requests. One as a WebSocket, the other as an XMLHttpRequest (AJAX). Since the 2 requests are launched simultaneously, they have the same set of cookies - *which in this case is **none***.

In each case, since the request provides no cookies, the server must generate a new HTTP Session. There server does not know that the two requests are from the same client, so 2 separate HTTP sessions are created.

If that's the case, then you could fix it quite simply by putting a filter in front of the index.html, that forces the creation of the session.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess your right with your assumption nr. 2. I use jetty as a own embeded server. And i guess, that the problem is that my static content file (the index.html) doesnt have start a Http Session yet. To solve my problem the index.html must start a new session, and then the WebSocketServlet and the SearchServlet should have the same session as the index.html 

My problem is, that i dont knwo how to implement it. I have a ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });

Where do I enable SESSION?

Comment: Seems to work now with an SessionHandler that wraps the ResourceHandler... Thank you for your help!